Coil Thumbnail issue how to change large image to thumbnail in Coil?
I have been working on Gallery app where I'm trying decoding or downscale large image to thumbnail,
I tried this method to downscale large image to small image but still I am still not getting a better performance in lazycolumn so few you guys have any better strategy you can discuss so  here is the Decoder Code.
 class ImageDecoder constructor(
private val  sourceResult : SourceResult,
                             private val  options: Options)  : Decoder {




@SuppressLint("NewApi")
override suspend fun decode(): DecodeResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        try {

            val file = sourceResult.source.file().toFile()

            val tempBitmap =   bitmapCache.get(file.path)

            if(tempBitmap!=null) {
                DecodeResult(
                    drawable = BitmapDrawable(options.context.resources, tempBitmap),
                    isSampled = false) }
            
            
         val    localBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createImageThumbnail(file,android.util.Size(200,200),null )
                bitmapCache.put(file.path ,localBitmap)
            DecodeResult(
                drawable = BitmapDrawable(options.context.resources, localBitmap),
                isSampled = false)

    } catch (e : Exception){

    DecodeResult(
        drawable = options.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.image_icon)!!,
        isSampled = false
    ) }}

and this is my ImageLoader Class Code in Application class
        @HiltAndroidApp
         class GalleryApplication  : Application() , ImageLoaderFactory , Configuration.Provider  {

@Inject
lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override val workManagerConfiguration: Configuration
    get() = Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()




override fun newImageLoader(): ImageLoader {
 return ImageLoader(this).newBuilder()
      .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .components {




            add(com.example.smartgalleryapp.decoder.ImageDecoder.ImageDecoderFactory())


        }
        .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .memoryCache {
            MemoryCache.Builder(this)
                .maxSizePercent(percent = 0.25)
                .strongReferencesEnabled(false)
                .build() }
        .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .diskCache {
            DiskCache.Builder()
                .maxSizePercent(percent = 0.25)
                .directory(cacheDir)
                .build() }
        .logger(DebugLogger()).build() }

}
